# Apex: How to Put Map of strings inside a List

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

Simple task but I am stuck -
Trying to put Map of string inside List. Need help please.

```
List<Map<string,string>> ss = new List<Map<string,string>>();
ss.add(new Map<string,string>()).putAll('red','blue');    //Error
System.debug(ss);
```

```
Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void putAll(String, String) from the type Object
```

Comment: Look at your parentheses very carefully. The compiler error should be pointing you towards what the problem is.

Comment: But it's still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `putAll`.

`putAll` either accepts a List of Map entries or a map of entries itself.

It should be something like this:

```
List<Map<String, String>> ss = new List<Map<String, String>>();
ss.add(new Map<String, String>{
        'red' => 'blue'
});
System.debug(ss);
```

And you can add multiple key value pair.

```
List<Map<String, String>> ss = new List<Map<String, String>>();
ss.add(new Map<String, String>{
        'red' => 'blue',
        'red1' => 'blue1'
});
System.debug(ss);
```

Comment: Awesome man. I truly appreciate that you understood my question completely unlike others and gave me the solution exactly what I was looking for !! You rock man. Thank you a bunch!!